# Selecting HTML datalist option does not trigger search event

Tags: javascript, html, django, input, datalist

I am developing a search engine for a website; now it's working fine and responding to input search keywords with no issues in its interaction with the (Django-based) local web server. The problem (well there are actually two, but I'm presenting only one here) is with the datalist. When I select an option from the list, although it goes into the search input field, nothing happens until I click the submit button.

I have written an event listener for each option, but I'm clearly missing something (important). Here's my minimal working code:

```js
      const searchForm = document.getElementById('search-form');
      const enter = document.getElementById('enter');
      let options = document.querySelectorAll(".option");
      options.forEach((item, index) => {
        item.addEventListener("click", () => {
          return searchForm.action;
        })
      })
```

```html
<form id="search-form" action ="{% url 'search' %}" method='POST'>
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input id="enter" type="search" list="options" name="query" />
      <datalist id="options">
        <option class="option" value="Happy">
        <option class="option" value="Puzzled">
      </datalist>
      <button id="go" type="submit"><strong>&#x1F50E;&#xFE0E;</strong></button>
      <button id="reset" type="reset"><strong>X</strong></button>
    </form>
```

Maybe the event should be something else; I've tried "keydown" and clicking twice but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `input` event fired on the input element. The input event's `data` property only shows the latest addition to the input's value by clicking an option,  typing or pasting, while the `value` property shows everything entered. Check it out in the snippet.

The event listeners on the option elements never get called - probably best to leave them out.

```js
"use strict";
const enter = document.getElementById('enter');
let options = document.querySelectorAll(".option");
options.forEach((item, index) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("clicked option ", this.value);
    return searchForm.action;
  })
  // debug:
  enter.oninput = e=>console.log('event.data: %s, enter.value: %s',e.data,enter.value);
})
```

```html
<form id="search-form" action ="" method='' onsubmit="console.log(event);return false">
  <input id="enter" type="search" list="options" name="query" />
  <datalist id="options">
    <option class="option" value="Happy">
    <option class="option" value="Puzzled">
  </datalist>
  <button id="go" type="submit"><strong>&#x1F50E;&#xFE0E;</strong></button>
  <button id="reset" type="reset"><strong>X</strong></button>
</form>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your input @traktor. I certainly learnt a lot from your suggestion, and as you hinted, the option elements aren't firing. In fact, as I later understood, the datalist element emits no events. Now whether that will change in HTML6, I don't know. Despite what I learnt from your suggestion, I was unable to engineer a solution from it. And as your suggestion was the only one posted, with no other suggestions forthcoming, I had to look elsewhere. I eventually came across an article by Keith (2020); I adapted his solution and it worked for me, which I'm posting here.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to my question, here is a solution I adapted from an article by Keith (2020) which worked for me:

JavaScript

```
  const enter = document.getElementById('enter');
  document.querySelectorAll('#enter[list]').forEach( function (formfield) {
    var options = document.getElementById('options');
    var lastlength = formfield.value.length;
    var checkInputValue = function (inputValue) {
      if (inputValue.length - lastlength > 1) {
        options.querySelectorAll('option').forEach( function(item) {
          if (item.value === inputValue) {
            formfield.form.submit();
          }
        });
      }
      lastlength = inputValue.length;
    };
    formfield.addEventListener('input', function () {
      checkInputValue(this.value);
    }, false);
  });
```

Reference:
Keith, J. (2020) *Submitting a form with datalist*. Available from: https://adactio.com/journal/17337 [Accessed October 31, 2022]