# How to reload a page when selecting an sorting option with the onchange parameter

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, bootstrap-4

I have a little problem.  I can't refresh the page when I select a parameter in the drop down list... When I tried it outside my page in a new document it was not a problem and I don't know if it's blocked somewhere by Bootstrap.. I'm still learning JS, so I might be making a mistake somewhere, but I have no idea where. I tried to reload one parameter see below and then I want to always reload the page when I click on the option value.. Thanks

Here is part of the code

```js
 function reloadF(obj){
                var theVal = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value;
                if (theVal == 'reload1') location.reload();
              }
```

```html
                    <select name="autnastranku" id="autnastranku" onchange="reloadF(this);">
                      <option value="0">Aut na stránku</option>
                      <option value="1">6</option>
                      <option value="2">9</option>
                      <option value="3">12</option>
                      <option value="reload1">reload</option>
                    </select>
```

[Image: Drop list with sorting options When I wanna reload the page if I click on reload, for example, see how I explain it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xysPq.png)

Comment: I had a similar problem about a year ago and asked a somewhat similar question on this website. I did find a solution and pasted it as an answer to my own question. Visit (my answer is the second one): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74253787/selecting-html-datalist-option-does-not-trigger-search-event/74261691#74261691

Comment: I'm just looking for how to do it via select without using the button.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using a external file for your js code you can perform the same like this, in the below code I am using a external script file for managing my js code and I thinks its the best approach to keep your js file away from other things.

```js
document.getElementById("autnastranku").addEventListener('input', function () {
  var theVal = this.value;
  if(theVal === 'reload1') {
      location.reload();
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Credit Card</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <select name="autnastranku" id="autnastranku">
    <option value="0">Aut na stránku</option>
    <option value="1">6</option>
    <option value="2">9</option>
    <option value="3">12</option>
    <option value="reload1">reload</option>
  </select>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Still nothing. When I select "Reload" option nothing happens. The page does not refresh and I don't really know where is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It works successfully, and it refreshes the page.
Run the code snippet in the question and try it.
It worked when I tried it.

Comment: That's weird. Nothing happens on my own website where I use Bootstrap 4. And I used this code and nothing happened. When I created a new file in Visual Studio for test it worked.